# Filtering by checkbox / useCallback returns empty state on first click: true but returns desired results on second click: true

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making a scheduling calendar that allows the user to filter by 12 variables (product subcategories). The state array returns an empty value on the initial click and the filter action is not completed until the box is unchecked then checked again. Each of the checkboxes works so I'm able to filter by multiple choices but they all have the same error in not firing on the first click.

```
const checkOptionOksana = useCallback((e) => {
        const checkedValue = e.target.id;
        const checked = e.target.checked;
        if (checked) {
            setFiltered((check) => [...check, checkedValue]);
            const newFilteredYogaClassesArray = classData.filter(singleClass => {
                return filtered.map(obj => obj === singleClass.instructor || obj === singleClass.yoga).some(val => val);
            });
            createYogaClassesArray(newFilteredYogaClassesArray);
            console.log(newFilteredYogaClassesArray);
        }
    }, [filtered]);
```

[Results in the console you see the first fire is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnpIb.jpg)

The onChange logic in my application:
`<input type="checkbox" onChange={e => checkOptionOksana(e)} id={'Oksana'} />`

In this [codepen using useCallback](https://codepen.io/trezy/pen/GROLXqo?editors=0110) you can see I followed the same process returning with an if statement. Only differing in how I set up the state array to populate with prior results and add to it. Everything in my app works fine except for the extra initial blank click.

Line 288 - handleFilterChange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what's happening here is that you're setting and accessing `filtered` in the same block. React batches state updates, so when you call `setFiltered`, the actual `filtered` variable is not immediately updated. So when you then call `filtered.map`, you're not working with the updated data.

You may be able to solve this with a temp variable:

```js
const checkOptionOksana = useCallback((e) => {
        const checkedValue = e.target.id;
        const checked = e.target.checked;
        if (checked) {
            // Creating the temp variable
            const tempFiltered = [...filtered, checkedValue];
            setFiltered(tempFiltered);
            const newFilteredYogaClassesArray = classData.filter(singleClass => {
                // Calling map on the temp variable instead of the state variable
                return tempFiltered.map(obj => obj === singleClass.instructor || obj === singleClass.yoga).some(val => val);
            });
            createYogaClassesArray(newFilteredYogaClassesArray);
            console.log(newFilteredYogaClassesArray);
        }
    }, [filtered]);
```

Comment: omg dude. You are my hero. That totally worked. I'm going to update and make sure everything else still flows together. Thank you so much!!